# How to extend div to cover video on smaller screen and make dropdown menu responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am making a website for my project and I encountered a problem that I couldn't figure it out how to fix it for couple of days already.

I used Bootstrap to make my website. It works quite well for large screen however on mobile screen, there are some problems.
1) On the "Movie" section, when resize one of two videos being pushed down but the border doesn't extend. I want to make the border extend when screen is resized but it fails to do so.
2) When the screen is resize, the last child of dropdown menu is overlapping with the list item below it, while I want to push the item Movie down when "dropdown menu" is click on mobile version.

Here is the link
https://jsfiddle.net/0b3qf2xn/

HTML

```
        <!-- Content-->
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-2 content" id="movie">
            <div class="row" id="movieWrapper">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1" id="movie-col">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uXALot_v3mQ"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5" id="movie-col">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uXALot_v3mQ"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- sidebar area start -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-10 sidebar">
            <div class="text-xs-center text-sm-left ">          

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" role="menu">   
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="btn-main">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About </i></a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="angaria.html">Subitem 01</a></li>

                            <li role="presentation"><a  role="menuitem" href="fujimoto.html">Subitem 02</a></li>

                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="komatsu.html">Subitem 03</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="movie-button"><a href="movie.html">Movie</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

P/s: I don't know why I can't recreate the dropdown problem is JSfiddle even though I already imported bootstrap and js file.

Comment: for dropdown menu issue, you need to include bootstrap js externally like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/0b3qf2xn/2/ . Right now you have included it in css. also you need need to select jquery through javascript button on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending code is in your `#moviewrapper` div. Remove the `height:100%` line to `height:auto;` and then you can vertically center the `col`

https://jsfiddle.net/4mrtr0oh/

Comment: And for things like these, create a simple sketch in Paint or something, It becomes clear what the structure you are aiming for.

Comment: Thank you. It looks great now. I am quite new to webdesign and this is my first project so I am still learning a lot. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Learn to use dev tools for debigging as well. Makes your life easier and helps you become knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Z-index with the menu bar.